# Modal Popup issue in asp.net Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I am very new to asp.net and creating my first project but I am having issue with dealing with Modal Popup. I want to use Modal up to add new record in to database but on the same web form I have another save button which also fire post back event to save all forms data.
So the issue is that main save button is not firing postback until I click button to show modal and click on add button on modal then Main save button fire postback but not before that.
I hope you understand my issue.
I don't know what is the issue.
Also, I kept Modal Popup html in  element? I think its required otherwise I won't be able to use add button event from modal popup. Is this right?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- please share your the code associated to your issue so we can help resolve the issue.

Comment: Hum, do you really want to use a popup form? I would suggest that you say display some list or grid rows of data. You then click on a row, or hit a button on that row. You then pass the "ID" selected and jump to a whole new page. The problem with a popup form is not only that of pop-up blockers, but such forms do NOT much allow you to work with an deal with post-backs. In most cases a post back will cause the popup to close - so you often lose the really "easy" ability to drop buttons that often (usually) do cause post backs.  So it is a lot easier to launch a page to edit that detail record